# Password not saving to auth_user table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Below is the code for the user registration. The password value is not saving to the auth_users table. I am using MySQL as my database.

Any help is highly appreciated TIA

### form.py

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email=self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

### view.py

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        print request.POST['username']
        print request.POST['password1']
        print request.POST['password2']
        form=MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register-success/')
    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=MyRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response("register.html",args,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### HTML

```
  <form method="post" class="form-signin" action="/register/">{% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
     <label for="users" class="sr-only">UserName</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" id="users" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input name="password1" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" required>
    <label for="inputPassword1" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input name="password2" type="password" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Is the form valid? What is saved to the `auth_users` table?

Comment: I am using the  default auth_user table that Djnago provides and added email to it

Comment: Yes form is valid. Other than password other details are saving to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `super()` incorrectly. You need to use the form class `MyRegistrationForm`, so that the save method of `UserCreationForm` is called and sets the password.

```
    user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that your def regiseter_user(request): view function has a superfluous "e" (regisEter).

Comment: That method is getting called not problem with typo error

Comment: action="/register/" can you confirm you are posting to the correct URL? It may help to add your urls.py to the question, along with imports.

Comment: It's pointing to correct method. The print statements that i kept in view.py are actually printing correctly. It's the password not saving to auth_user table